# Simple MVC Error Page

Tags: php, routes

Alright, I'm attempting to make an error page for my MVC source I've been working on.

Stock /inc/route.php

```
<?php

  Route::set('index.php', function() {
    Index::CreateView('Index');
  });

  Route::set('modelTest', function() {
    ModT::CreateView('ModT');
  });

 ?>
```

Stock /class/route.class.php

```
<?php

  class Route {

    public static $validRoutes = array();

    public static function set($route, $function) {

      self::$validRoutes[] = $route;

      if($_GET['return'] == $route) {
        $function->__invoke();
      } else {
        echo "Route not found";
      }

    }

  }

 ?>
```

I've tried else statements, Then it echos out the error with the page itself, I tried within array then when it errors it echos as many times as their are routes.

I was hoping someone could point me in a correct direction to solving this.

Comment: You want an error page is no route exists?

Comment: Indeed, if no routes are found.

Comment: How is this related to MVC?

Comment: @tereško Cause it's custom MVC software? It's more of a routing question. I'll update it.